# How I can pass this data format "27/04/2014 00:40" to this: "Sunday, 27 April, 2014"?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I normally use data in this format "27/04/2014 00:40" with **this code below**:

```
$f['date'] = $_POST['data'];


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Date:</span>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="data" value="
             <?php 
              if(isset($_POST['date'])) 
                   echo $f['date']; 
              else echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); ?>" 
             />
   </label>
</form>
```

But now Im trying to find how I can create a **format like**: Sunday, 27 April, 2014

Do you know how we can do this?

Comment: So you just copied that code from somewhere?  I would think if you can use `date` it would be trivial.

Comment: Yes I copy this format date('d/m/Y H:i:s') to test from my google search!

Answer (score 3):

You want to first parse the date with `$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $f['date'])` and then format according to your new requirement: `date_format('l, d F, Y', $date)`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution work and the Sharikov Vladislav solution also works! But Im having a little problem now, because Im having the format like I want but it is in english, it is possible to change for my language?

Comment: @OzzC Please take a look at [PHP: strftime](http://us2.php.net/strftime) and [PHP: setlocale](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). They may be of use, however if you are not able to localize the date with these, you may need to do localization/translation yourself.

Comment: @OzzC I edited my answer, hope this will help you: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23318151/2898694)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo date('l, j F, Y');
```

Read `date` function php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you need non-english names of months and names of each day you can add it by yourself.

Array for month names:

```
$translatedMonths = array(
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February', 
    '03' => 'March',   
    '04' => 'April', 
    '05' => 'May',   
    '06' => 'June', 
    '07' => 'July',   
    '08' => 'August', 
    '09' => 'September',   
    '10' => 'October', 
    '11' => 'November', 
    '02' => 'December'  
);
```

Array for week days:

```
$translatedWeeks = array(
    '0' => 'Sunday',    
    '1' => 'Monday',    
    '2' => 'Tuesday',   
    '3' => 'Thirsday',  
    '4' => 'Wednesday', 
    '5' => 'Friday',    
    '6' => 'Saturday'
);
```

Now you just need to build output string:

```
echo $translatedWeeks[date('w')] . ", " . date('j') . " " . $translatedMonths[date('m')] . " " . date('Y');
```

To use this, you just need to translate names of months and days of weeks.

Example here: http://ideone.com/BserJo

**Note,** that `date()` function returns string, so you have to build assoc arrays appropriately.

Hope, this will help you.